# Sharing map of settings across groovy script files

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Currently I am having one jenkinsfile which in process of development has grown to huge size. Mostly it contains some groovy methods used in pipeline, but I would like to place groovy scripts in separate files in other repository and than checkout every time when I need those scripts. Those works on a maps of settings which is commonly used in methods.  How can I share those maps in script files? I can't use shared libraries because of security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to shared library is the [`load`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#-load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) step, which loads and evaluates the given groovy script file.

**settings.groovy:**

```
[
  answer: 42,
  question: 'tbd'
]
```

**main.groovy:**

```
def settings = load 'settings.groovy'
echo "The answer is: ${settings.answer}"
```

**Output:**

`The answer is: 42`

Comment: Thanks. After some refactoring it should actually help